# prove a number is irrational

Tags: real-numbers

If $x$ and $y$ are irrational numbers then $x$ to the power of $y$ is irrational
I am asked to prove or disprove this statement.
To do so I got an idea to use the contra-positive, for that I need to prove if $x$ to the power of $y$ is rational then $x$ and $y$ are rational. I took $\ln$ for both sides, because keeping some element in power would make the sum more difficult, now I have $y\ln(x) = \ln(p/q)$. How could I show that $x$ and $y$ are rational?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational, $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, but $\biggl(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\biggr)^{\sqrt{2}} = (\sqrt{2})^2=2$ is very much rational. Your take on this?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: It doesn’t really matter whether $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational: if not, we can take $x=y=\sqrt2$, and if so, your example works.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right, but I thought I would complicate things. Besides, the Gelfond-Schneider theorem says that $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is transcendental, forget about irrational.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: But someone asking this question is unlikely to be aware of the Gelfond-Schneider theorem or to have any idea whether $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational, so the extra complication is probably necessary.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. You are right, there are nicer counterexamples than the one I've given.

Comment: The argument can be stated thus: If $\sqrt 2^{\sqrt2}$ is rational, then it is a counterexample to the proposed statement.  But if it is irrational, then $\left( \sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2}\right)^{\sqrt 2}$ is a counterexample, since it is $\sqrt 2^2=2$. You don't need difficult results like the Gelfond–Schneider theorem to understand that. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

$e$ and $\log2$ are irrational but $e^{\log2}=2$ is not.

---

In particular, [$e$ is transcendental](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m400su06/transcendence%20of%20e.pdf). This theorem allows to prove the irrationality of $\log n,$ $n\in\mathbb{N\setminus\{0,1\}}$. Assume $\log n=a/b$ for some integers $a,b$. Then $e=n^{b/a}$, which makes it a solution of the algebraic equation $x^a-n^b=0$; absurd. Hence $\log n$ is irrational.

Comment: To expand on this answer, this is true because it is known that $e$ is both irrational and transcedental; the proofs are not *too* difficult. $\log 2$ is irrational because $\log 2$ rational would imply $e$ algebraic, contradiction.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Yes. Thanks.

Comment: @Deepak: I don't think s/he was referring to Gelfond. Let $\log 2$ be the real number $r$ s.t. $e^r=2$ (there clearly *does* exist such a unique $r$). Then $e=2^{1/\log2}$. If $\log 2=a/b$ for some integers $a,b$, then $e$ would be algebraic (in particular, it would be the solution of the algebraic equation $x^a-2^b=0$), a contradiction.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Ah I see, thanks.

Comment: How do you prove $\log_e 2$ is irrational?  Should that be added to the answer?  (Proofs that $e$ is irrational are found in many textbooks and are short and simple.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

An elementary solution: $x = \log_2 3$ is irrational (otherwise if it equals $m/n$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$, $2^m = 3^n$ contradicting unique prime factorization). Now $\sqrt 2$ is irrational and $(\sqrt 2)^{2x} = 3$ is a counter-example.

Comment: For this you can get by with a far weaker statement than uniqueness of prime factorizations, namely the fact that a product of two odd numbers is odd. $\qquad$

Comment: But the way I wrote is much more general, it suggests a much greater family of similar examples. I often have such additional, hidden reasons in my writing. With that said, of course you are right.